# Error with form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm having errors in validation of my form.

Here's the javascript:

```
function ValidateForm(){
email=document.getElementbyId("email").value;
confirmemail=document.getElementById("confirmemail").value;
password=document.getElementById("password").value;
confirmpassword=document.getElementById("confirmpassword").value;
 errors = " ";

if (email == " ") {
erros += "Please enter your email \n";
}

emailcheck = /^.+@.+\..{2,4}$/;
if (email.match(emailcheck)) { }
else {
errors += "Please check your email \n";
}

if (email.match(confirmemail)) {}
else {
errors += "Email don't match \n";
}

if ( errors != "") {
alert(errors);
}
else { } 
}
```

And here's the form part of HTML:

```
<form action="/LoginData/" method="post">
<label>Email</label>
<input id="email" type="email" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Your email id"      name="email" required>
<label>Confirm Email</label>
<input id="confirmemail" type="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Confirm your Email id" name="confirmemail" required>
<br/>
<br/>
<label>Password</label>
<input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
<label>Confirm Password</label>
<input id="confirmpassword" type="password" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm  your Password" required>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Account">
</form>
```

It doesn't show the alert message even if i fill the fields with wrong input.

(Note: i'm using external JavaScript file)

I'm using the javascript for IE8 because i want to make the webpage run properly on it.
And it doesn't show the alert for any of the fields in IE.
A example of what i'm trying to build: [1](http://aharrisbooks.net/jad/chap_07/validate.html)http://aharrisbooks.net/jad/chap_07/validate.html

Comment: Where do you call validate form?

Comment: Hi Tanmay! You should consider providing more details regarding *when* it doesn't display the alert message. Is it for all fields? Only the e-mail field? I'm noticing that you have a typo in the validation for the latter, as it's assigning `erros` and not `errors`. Also, as far as validation goes, you aren't double-checking that the entered e-mail address matches the "confirmation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call ValidateForm() in you code.

In this scenario calling it on submit will be the best option something like `onsubmit="return validateForm()"`;

Also it has camel case problem. Should be getElementById instead of getElementbyId. Check your syntax Errors in browser console.

Comment: Ok after i added this i think there is error with something else  When i run the page on IE with the method you told, this comes up "Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)
Timestamp: Wed, 7 Jan 2015 02:29:56 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 2
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: file:///S:/Users/Rajesh/Desktop/Rulers%20Online/Register.js" So i think there is error with the <script> tag. Thank you

Comment: I will recommend to put empty checks on length like `email.length==0` rather then email=="". Also you need to return true and false for better implementation

Comment: @Tanmay it camel case problem. Should be getElementById instead of getElementbyId. Syntax Errors

Answer (score 0):

You must put

```
onsubmit="return validateForm()"
```

So

```
<form action="/LoginData/" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<label>Email</label>
<input id="email" type="email" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Your email id"      name="email" required>
<label>Confirm Email</label>
<input id="confirmemail" type="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Confirm your Email id" name="confirmemail" required>
<br/>
<br/>
<label>Password</label>
<input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
<label>Confirm Password</label>
<input id="confirmpassword" type="password" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm  your Password" required>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Account">
</form>
```

in the form tag in order to use your custom validation before submitting data.

You currently use HTML5 validation tag's so even if your cusom JS function is not called, you should see HTML5 validation with new browsers. You can see browsers that are more compliant than others with HTML5 : http://caniuse.com/#search=html5.